# What is a good proxy for government quality?

Tags: macroeconomics, applied-econometrics, regression, open-economy-macro, paneldata

Is it ok to use corruption as a proxy for government quality?

Comment: Your title and your body is asking two different questions, I like the title more :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using corruption is part of it but a bit restrictive way to measure government "quality". You may use aggregate indicators as the one developed by the [Worldwide Governance Indicators (WGI) project](https://info.worldbank.org/governance/wgi/#home) from the World Bank. They reports aggregate and individual governance indicators for over 200 countries and territories over the period 1996–, for six dimensions of governance:

1. Voice and Accountability
2. Political Stability and Absence of Violence
3. Government Effectiveness
4. Regulatory Quality
5. Rule of Law
6. **Control of Corruption**

---

***What is Governance ?***

According to the WGI project Governance consists of the traditions and institutions by which authority in a country is exercised.  This includes the process by which governments are selected, monitored and replaced; the capacity of the government to effectively formulate and implement sound policies; and the respect of citizens and the state for the institutions that govern economic and social interactions among them.

Comment: Thank you but since it was only from 1996 I used Bayesian corruption index instead so that I could have more data.